# Why "safe navigation operator" instead of "safe navigational operator"?

Tags: modifiers, attributive-nouns

There is a terminology "safe navigation operator" in programming.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

But "navigation" is a noun, why an adjective "navigational" is not used?

I think this question is on border of a programming question and an English question. If you guys think I should ask this question in Stack Overflow, I'll move to there.

Comment: Because it's the same that we call + the plus operator or the addition operator rather than the additional operator, I suppose.

Comment: It's a [noun adjunct](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html).  In English, you can use a noun to modify another noun, like "race horse" or "apple tree" or "navigation operator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the underlying operator is called a

> navigation operator

and a

> safe navigation operator

is a navigation operator that has been made "safe" by the way it returns its argument values.

> In programming languages where the **navigation operator** (e.g. ".") leads to an error if applied to a null object, the **safe navigation operator** stops the evaluation of a method/field chain and returns null as the value of the chain expression.

Why the underlying operator is not called a "navigational operator" is a different question.